# Put string version of operator in between its operands

Tags: r

If I have a variable holding a string representation of a comparative operator such as:

```
> comparison <- "=="
```

how can I interpolate this string version of the binary operator between its operands? E.g.

```
> 2 <insert comparison> 2
TRUE
```

NB. I do not want to use `mapply(get(comparison),2,2` since I intend to put `2 <insert comparison> 2` as an argument to `which`.

Comment: Actually, it's fine. I thought that `which` would use the wrong argument to get the indexbut that was because there was sth wrong with my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you don't want to use `mapply`, but `do.call` is probably better anyway.

```
comparison <- "=="
do.call(comparison, list(2,2))

which( do.call(comparison, list(2,0:4)) )
```